Issues with next.js setup
USER@DESKTOP-AHR4HO7 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/propmall-next-app
$ npx create-next-app@latest
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall lstat
npm error path C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm'

I have reinstalled node.js and made sure npm is installed.

looks like your internet block the fetching file from next app
